# Find zero of this exponential equation

Tags: exponentiation

I know that you can find numerically answer to this, but is it possible to express x somehow algebraically $e^{\frac{2}{x}}=x$?

Comment: The Lambert-$W$ function isn't algebraic, but it may nevertheless be what you actually want.

Answer (score 1):

$$1 = \frac{1}{x} \mathrm{e}^{\frac{2}{x}}$$
$$2  = \frac{2}{x} \mathrm{e}^{\frac{2}{x}}$$
$$\mathrm{W}(2) = \frac{2}{x}$$
$$x = \frac{2}{\mathrm{W}(2)} \approx 2.34575$$
Where $\mathrm{W}(z)$ is the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).

A good tutorial can be found [here](http://2000clicks.com/mathhelp/BasicSimplifyingLambertWFunction.aspx), where we see that for $a=b\mathrm{e}^{b}$, we have $b=\mathrm{W}(a)$